# Custom VIsualForce Page Property

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, dynamic-visualforce

In layouts, there's settings for visualforce page when you click on the wrench icon to set width and height.

[image]

Is there a way to add a custom property onto this wizard? Such adding a new checkbox and accessing it in the visualforce page?

I've searched around and was fairly suprised no one has digged into this.

Comment: What would you like to use such functionality for ? You may want to look into using custom settings in your VF pages.

Comment: Yeah I was looking into custom settings and its a viable solution but its a lot more complicated than what I want to do. I'm just trying to show fields from a related object when the admin user allows them to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The items presented on the configuration light box are standard layout properties. You can't add custom settings here. In fact, you can't even add custom URL parameters at this point.

Comment: Any good workaround for this? Right now I have custom settings that user can pick and choose in the actual visualforce page. But the problem with this is that all users are allow to change the settings. Is there a way to limit it to users that are able to change the page layout? or is there a better workaround?

Comment: @Oakage Depending on the purpose, you might either (a) check the user's profile permissions to see if they have permission to customize the application, or (b) use a hierarchical custom setting to allow each user to choose their own settings.